ASP.NET Core Project hangs on 'Build', on new laptop
I've been working on an ASP.NET application that runs in a Docker container. After getting a new laptop, I installed Visual Studio 2022 and Docker Desktop. I cloned my project from GitHub, but when I try to build the project, the output only shows "Build Started at..." and nothing else happens, no matter how long I wait. I see no new containers being created in Docker Desktop, and there are no error messages.
I've ensured that my Docker Desktop settings match those on my old laptop. I've also tried copying the solution folder directly from my old laptop, but the problem persists.
How can I diagnose where the build process is getting stuck?
Steps I've taken so far:
Installed the latest updates for Windows, Visual Studio, and Docker Desktop
Reinstalled Visual Studio
Reinstalled Docker Desktop
Checked Docker Desktop settings to ensure they match the old laptop
Copied the solution folder from my old laptop to the new one (same problem)

Any advice on how to pinpoint the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Try to remove all the docker-related files and setting and re-add docker support , try again. Seems it's known issue for project in a new machine.

So, the problem is solved.
I deleted my entire solution and cloned the project from Github for the third time.
Thank you Jason Pan, your comment is what made me try to clone my project again.
I think you were right about there being a problem with the docker file.
I unfortunately don't understand what caused the problem.
